# Cucumber step not found

Tags: typescript, protractor, cucumber

I am following https://github.com/igniteram/protractor-cucumber-typescript
In the feature file I have added a When-Sentence

```
WHEN something else
```

and an according step in the stepdefinition:

```
When(/^something else $/, async () => {
    return expect(browser.getTitle()).to.eventually.equal('Google');
});
```

This is the file with stepdefinitions (homePage.ts):

```
import { browser } from 'protractor';
import { SearchPageObject } from '../pages/searchPage';
import { defineSupportCode } from 'cucumber';
let chai = require('chai').use(require('chai-as-promised'));
let expect = chai.expect;

defineSupportCode(({ Given, When, Then }) => {
    let search: SearchPageObject = new SearchPageObject();

Given(/^I am on google page$/, async () => {
    await expect(browser.getTitle()).to.eventually.equal('Google');
});

When(/^something else $/, async () => {
    return expect(browser.getTitle()).to.eventually.equal('Google');
});

Then(/^and something more$/,() => {
    return expect(browser.getTitle()).to.eventually.equal('Google');
});

})
```

When I run protractor, the step is not found:

```
1) Scenario: Cucumber Google Search - features\cucumber.feature:4
Step: When something else - features\cucumber.feature:6
Message: Undefined. Implement with the following snippet:

   When('something else', function (callback) {
     // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
     callback(null, 'pending');
   });
```

How can I make this step be found?

Comment: Is this because you have an extra space at the end of "something else"? i.e. it should be `When(/^something else$/` instead of `When(/^something else $/`

Comment: ...that was it, thanks! Sometimes you cannot see the wood for the trees